# C++ compilation problem

Tags: c++

Pretty much forgot how to code C++ at all. Anyway, here is the problem.

I am trying to load a class defined in a .cpp file I wrote myself.

In the main function:

```
... ...
 #include "loader.h"
... ...
 model load_model("TechnologyEnterpriseFacility_Day_Gregor/
               TechnologyEnterpriseFacility_Gregor.model");
```

the header file looks like this:

```
 #ifndef LOADER_H_
 #define LOADER_H_

 class model
 {
   public:
    int textures [];
    float vertices[][3];
    float triangles[][13]; 
    model(const char*); // constructor
 };

 #endif /* LOADER_H_ */
```

and here is the .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include "loader.h"

using namespace std;

model::model(const char* filename)
{
    ... ...
```

When I compile the main function, I got error message:

```
gcc -o glrender glrender.cpp -lglut
/tmp/cc3sWIgb.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
glrender.cpp:(.text+0x11b): undefined reference to `model::model(char const*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

comments and ideas are welcomed, thanks.

Comment: Is your main function in the same file as the cpp file that implements your class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't you forget to insert `model.cpp` in your compilation line ?

```
gcc -o glrender glrender.cpp model.cpp -lglut
```

Comment: oh, gee, I am so rusty ...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the implementation file along with the header file. Either directly import it into your main program:

```
#include "implementation.cpp";
```

Or compile it separately with the compiler:

```
myCompiler -flags main.cpp implement.cpp
```

Either would work, but the latter is more maintainable and professional.